# From a group action on $TM$ to one on $T^*M$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

I have a Lie group action $\varphi$ of $G$ on $TM$ (tangent bundle of $M$) and I want to define an associated action on $T^*M$ (cotangent bundle of $M$), where $M$ is a smooth manifold. I know that $TM$ and $T^*M$ are diffeomorphic (but I don't think I have seen before an explicit expression for this mapping). Thus what I think to do is define the action $$\psi:G\times T^*M\rightarrow T^*M $$ by means of this diffeomorphism $f:T^*M\rightarrow TM$ as $\psi(g,m) := \varphi(g,f(m)) = f^*\varphi_g(m)$.

I think this is a reasonable approach, however before going on I want to be sure this is correct. It would be even helpful if someone tells me the explicit expression of this $f$, or how to construct it.

Comment: There is no canonical way to do this. Each choice of Riemannian metric on $M$ gives you a bundle isomorphism $TM\cong T^{\ast}M$ that fiberwise identifies $T_pM$ with its dual $T_p^{\ast}M$ by virtue of the inner product. Conversely, there's a natural evaluation bundle morphism $TM\times T^{\ast}M\rightarrow M\times\mathbb{R}$ that is non-denegerate on each fiber, so that a choice of bundle isomorphism $TM\cong T^{\ast}M$ yields a bundle metric on $TM$ via this map. The bundle isomorphisms $TM\cong T^{\ast}M$ are naturally in bijection with metrics on $M$.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought something similar. So if I have them embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I can use the one given by the induced Euclidean metric. Thanks. While for the induced action, is the reasoning I presented above correct?

Comment: If you have $M$ embedded in $\Bbb R^n$ you can use the metric induced from the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^n$ to get an isomorphism from $TM$ to $T^*M$, yes (this "Euclidean" isomorphism is what linear algebra calls "taking the transpose"). But then we get the same issue in extrinsic form: the isomorphism you get depends on the embedding.

Comment: Ok, sure, thanks @Arthur

Comment: I think the formula should be $\Psi(g,m)=f^{-1}(\phi(g,f(m))).$  And yes, there are different $f$s you can pick, but the all lead to equivalent actions on $T^{\ast}M$.

Comment: @Thorgott: All you need to get a diffeo between $TM$ and T^{\ast}M$ is a non-degenerate bilinear form.  Because of this, it seems to me that only a proper subset of choices of bundle isomorphism gives a Riemannian metric.  Am I misunderanding how you create the metric from the isomorphism?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Ah no, I wasn't thinking properly. The construction I described is the correct one, but it only yields a non-degenerate bilinear form in general (and, of course, the converse holds too). More precisely, we have natural bundle isomorphisms $\mathrm{Hom}(TM,T^{\ast}M)\cong T^{\ast}M\otimes T^{\ast}M\cong(\mathrm{Sym}(TM))^2$, which identify the isomorphisms $TM\cong T^{\ast}M$ precisely with the pointwise non-degenerate bilinear forms. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, it is much more clear now. If you want to write an answer, I will accept it as an answer

Comment: In general it seems you don't actually get an action on $T^*M$. But if the action $G\circlearrowright TM$ is fiber-preserving, it descends to an action $G\circlearrowright M$. Then cotangent lifts yield an action $G \circlearrowright T^*M$.